# Windows 2012 extremely slow interface

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

I have a windows server with 2x E5-2620 cpus and 32 gigs a RAM. The only thing running on this box is SQL Server.  CPU is very low.

The GUI of windows is extremely sluggish. Opening the start menu, searching, etc takes minutes. Type a letter...wait...another letter wait.  Opening control panel and such takes forever.

The database on the server is fast as ever. I moved the database from a busier box to this one and I am seeing huge performance gains.  So it's not like the entire windows server is slow, just the UI.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you connecting to it? Directly or via RDP

Comment: By "CPU is very low" do you mean in Task Manager? It may be that the system is performing disk activities, you may need to install drivers, does the machine have an anti-virus that's doing a background scan, what does Resource Monitor say, is the computer checking for/installing updates in the background?

Comment: @Dave Over RDP  And yes I mean in task manager.  Device manager shows all drivers are installed.  No anti-virus yet, it's a fresh machine that's a day old.

Comment: Opening Device manager takes like 4-5 mins.  Sits there in (not responding) in the title bar.

Comment: How do you know it's running slowly and not the response time of the UI? Since task manager is showing it's not using much resource and your description is GUI only I'd suspect the issue is connection or similar.

Comment: @Dave It's possible but I run lots of RDP connections to the same data center with ease.  I'm also on fiber so it's not a speed issue. I thought it could be RDP but why would that cause Device manager to take 4 mins to open?

Comment: Are you able to try it? At least it means we can rule it out (see my updated answer)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since task manager is showing it's not using much resource and your description is GUI only I'd suspect the issue is connection or similar.

To test it, simply open up the settings in the RDP window (before you connect) and change the colours and size in the Display tab. Also consider the Experience tab as you can choose a more appropriate connection speed.

Lastly, I've heard some say that not adding to bring over your printers and clipboard can help under the local resources tab

Another reason could be a simple as it not having the correct driver? Check to see if the server is up to date?

You said you've moved to a new machine - does this have the same software/hardware (any firewall etc) which may throttle (I know unlikely to do it, but I include for completeness)

Comment: I think the bitmap caching option was the culprit.  This seems to have helped.  Thanks!